# Simple sum in IJVM

Tags: cpu-architecture, alu

Suppose we need to make a sum of two binary numbers in ijvm, for example:

100 + 11 = 111

Translating all in ijvm:

```
ILOAD arg1 //100
ILOAD arg2 // 11                
IADD
ISTORE i
```

Without making any changes to the code, what the content of the variable i ?
as they represented in ijvm numbers? A simple add enough to make a sum? Why do I need a shift right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte code would look like

```
0x15 0x02
0x15 0x03
0x60
0x36 0x01
```

where 0x02 is the offset from LV to arg1, 0x03 is the offset from LV to arg2, and 0x01 is the offset from LV to i.

The local variable i would have 111 in it, if local variable arg1 has 100 and local variable arg2 has 11.

The stack would look like this before the IADD

```
011 <- SP
100 <- operand stack starts here
011 <- LV + 3
100 <- LV + 2
xxx <- LV + 1
xxx <- LV
```

The stack would look like this after the ISTORE

```
011 <- LV + 3
100 <- LV + 2
111 <- LV + 1
xxx <- LV
```

The code you supplied will perform the addition. You do not need to shift.

Response to comment about overflow:

Create a grid for adding two 2-bit numbers. 00 01 10 11 across the top and along the side. 

  `| 00 01 10 11|
00|            |
01|            |
10|            |
11|            |`

In the grid, show the result of the arithmetic, excluding overflow. Circle the entries that cause overflow. Such a table might give you a clue for detecting overflow, without looking at the carry bit.

Comment: Assuming that you enter two values that exceed the permitted 32-bit, how can I manage the phenomenon of overflow?